# How to trigger a macro for every data set containing a keyword

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I'm doing a crash course on SAS macros and I'm stuck at one exercise. I have to create a macro, that will create a proc contents tables for every data set, that contains a keyword. I know how to do that using call execute, but I need this using proc sql and %do loop.
My attempt:

```
%macro contents(data=&syslast);
   proc contents data=&data; 
      title "&data"; 
   run;
%mend contents;

%macro ContentsAll(keyword);
    select libname||'.'||memname
        into :dsn1-
            from sashelp.vstabvw
                where upcase(memname) like %upcase("%quote(%)&&keyword%")
        ;
    quit;
    %do i=1 %to &sqlobs;
        %contents(data=&&dsn&i);
    %end;
%mend ContentsAll;

options mlogic mprint;
%ContentsAll(class);
options nomlogic nomprint;
```

I know there is some issue with a select statement, but I have no idea how to fix it. And where statement has an unprotected variable (my attempts at fixing it just break the where clause alltogether.

Comment: Do you want every dataset from every libref whose name contains that string?  Or only from one particular libref?

Comment: Every libref. Which made a thing a bit harder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, good job. It's so good that I'm almost sorry you're only missing the Proc SQL Statement :-)

```
%macro contents(data=&syslast);
   proc contents data=&data; 
      title "&data"; 
   run;
%mend contents;

%macro ContentsAll(keyword);
    proc sql noprint;
    select libname||'.'||memname
        into :dsn1-
            from sashelp.vstabvw
                where upcase(memname) like %upcase("%quote(%)&&keyword%")
        ;
    quit;
    %do i=1 %to &sqlobs;
        %contents(data=&&dsn&i);
    %end;
%mend ContentsAll;

options mlogic mprint;
%ContentsAll(class);
options nomlogic nomprint;
```

Comment: Oh god, how on earth could I miss that? 
What about the second part? Protecting the variable? Since I get a warning: "Apparent invocation of macro CLASS not resolved." And that could be potentially problematic if I search with a keyword that happens to be the name of a macro.

Comment: I haven't tested this, but I would think you can get around that warning by using the %NrStr Macro Quoting Function instead of the %quote function. The Class of Quote quoting functions mask resolved macro values. Str class function mask plain non-resolved text.

Comment: With: "    where upcase(memname) like %upcase("%nrstr(%%)&&keyword%")    " I still get the same warning. What worked  in the end was this: "   where upcase(memname) like "%quote(%)%upcase(&&keyword%)"    "

Comment: `libname||'.'||memname` will not work when the libname is less than 8 characters long.  Use `catx('.',libname,memname)` instead.

Comment: Avoid the use of % by using CONTAINS instead of LIKE. `upcase(memname) contains "&keyword"`.  Or since you want KEYWORD to be uppercase use %qupcase() to add the quoting and the uppercase.  `upcase(memname) like "%%qupcase(&keyword)%"`

Comment: Is it even possible to have a libname with less than 8 characters? I mean, it just feed blancs if it's less (most of mine libnames are less than 8 chars). Will use cats/catx anyway, as it makes the title clearer.

And thanks for the hint. CONTAINS is cleaner (I'm kinda new to SAS and I didn't know it existed)

Comment: If the name is shorter than 8 then the || operator will include the blanks. `proc contents data=mylib   .mydata` is not going to work because of the spaces.

Comment: But it did work? The only difference was that the title looked weird with all those blancs. But the proc contents tables were fine.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to create all of those macro variables.  Just keep the list of names in actual data.  You can use CALL EXECUTE() to generate the code you want to run for each member in the list.

Note that the variables LIBNAME and MEMNAME will already be in uppercase when pulled from the DICTIONARY.MEMBERS metadata that the view SASHELP.VSTABVW uses.  But the user passing in a value for the KEYWORD parameter might not have entered uppercase letters.

```
%macro ContentsAll(keyword);
data _null_;
  set sashelp.vstabvw ;
  where memname contains "%qupcase(&keyword)" ;
  call execute(cats('%nrstr(%contents)(data=',libname,'.',memname,')'));
run;
%mend ContentsAll;
```

Comment: Yes, I know that CALL EXECUTE is a simpler (and I guess faster) solution. But the course called for a solution using proc SQL (well, both really, but I only had problems with proc SQL one)